# SDO_GEOM.SDO_INTERSECTION gives strange results

Tags: oracle, geometry, oracle-spatial

I'm using oracle spatial analysis to compute intersection of two geometries, but I'm getting really strange results.

- Yellow is geometry1
- Blue is geometry2
- Red is intersection: `SDO_GEOM.SDO_INTERSECTION(geometry1,geometry2, 0.00005);`

[image]

How is that even possible? Should I use some other function?

Answer (score 1):

I've found out that the problem is not in the geometry, but in the visualisation in the SQL Developer. 
I've exported the geometry to KML format and it looks fine when viewed in Google Maps.

Comment: Have you tried rendering it in Oracle MapViewer (although I suspect results will be similar). What SRID are you using?

Comment: SRID is 8307. I didn't try mapviewer, but when I export any of the data, everything seems fine in different renderer(google maps). So I assume it's some problem in the SQL Developer.